# How can I change screen without using a button click in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I want to change screen when someone successfully logs in. I know how to get access to my controller class but not the specific screen.

```
[NRGramKit loginInWebView:self.webView loginLoadingCallback:^(BOOL loading){
    NSLog(@"Loading");

} finishedCallback:^(IGUser* user,NSString* error){
    // yay - you are now authenticated, NRGramKit remembers the credentials
    LoggedInViewController *loggedInViewController = [[LoggedInViewController alloc]init];
    loggedInViewController.myUser = user;
    [self presentViewController:loggedInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}];
```

Comment: What do you mean by screen? Is that a subview of your view controller?

Comment: I wont the app to change to another screen that I have in my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically instantiate a view controller from a storyboard by using the `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method on an instance of `UIStoryboard`.

```
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil];
MyViewController *vc = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Page"];
// use view controller and its view as required
```

#### UIViewController -storyboard

If your view controller came from a storyboard it's `storyboard` property will return the storyboard it came from. So you can skip the storyboard initialization.

```
// within a view controller
OtherViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherIdentifier"];
```

#### Setting the identifier

- open storyboard
- select view controller
- open identity inspector (panel where you can set subclass)
- set "Storyboard ID"

[image: Setting the view controller's storyboard ID]

Comment: Thank you, but where do I set a name on my storyboard?
I just wrote the file name and I did get this error 

"Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboar"


my code
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboar" bundle:nil];

Comment: It's working now, THANK YOU for the god explanation :D !